# Why closures are not capturing the same variable with let?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, closures, ecmascript-5

Here is a canonical sample illustrating the issue with **local variables captured by closures**:

```
var a = []
for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    a.push(() => i)
}
var v = a.map(f => f())
console.log(v)
```

The result is `[ 4, 4, 4 ]`, so far so good.

But when qualifying `i` with `let` instead of `var`:

```
var a = []
for (let i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    a.push(() => i)
}
var v = a.map(f => f())
console.log(v)
```

we get `[ 1, 2, 3 ]`.

I don't understand why: even though `let` scopes `i` to the `for` loop, there is always a single `i` for all the closures, so this should not changed anything.

And for me the `for` loop with `let` should be equivalent to:

```
var a = []
{ // Scope for the loop
    let i = 1
    do {
        a.push(() => i)
    }
    while (++i <= 3)
}
var v = a.map(f => f())
console.log(v)
```

like AFAIK it is in C, C++, Java, C#... and which gives `[ 4, 4, 4 ]`.

Obviously I'm wrong, so what am I missing?

Comment: There is not a single `i` for all the closures, but one `i` for each closure.

Comment: The `let` keyword in the `for` loop initialiser doesn't create the variable outside of the loop, it creates a new variable inside the block scope of the loop body in every iteration.

Comment: Thanks, indeed the semantics is really different from the other languages I've mentioned, and the compiler handles this case in a special manner if I understand well.